# What does this Glassfish3+ CORBA error message means?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I get the following error message on my Glassfish 3+ server. Does someone know what the problem could be?

```
[#|2014-02-19T09:58:41.963+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=55;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00410025: Write of message exceeded TCP timeout : max wait time = 6,000 ms, total time spent blocked, waiting to write = 7,280 ms.
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: WARNING: IOP00410025: Write of message exceeded TCP timeout : max wait time = 6,000 ms, total time spent blocked, waiting to write = 7,280 ms.  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 25  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.transportWriteTimeoutExceeded(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.write(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:691)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.writeTo(CDROutputObject.java:234)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.sendWithoutLock(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:985)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendFragment(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:151)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendMessage(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:165)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.finishSendingMessage(CDROutputObject.java:200)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.sendResponse(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1554)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
|#]

[#|2014-02-19T09:58:41.965+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=55;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|IOP00710134: Exception occurred in handleRequest for a Request message
org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: WARNING: IOP00710134: Exception occurred in handleRequest for a Request message  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 134  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.exceptionInHandleRequestForRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: WARNING: IOP00410025: Write of message exceeded TCP timeout : max wait time = 6,000 ms, total time spent blocked, waiting to write = 7,280 ms.  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 25  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.transportWriteTimeoutExceeded(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.write(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:691)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.writeTo(CDROutputObject.java:234)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.sendWithoutLock(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:985)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendFragment(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:151)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteStream.sendMessage(BufferManagerWriteStream.java:165)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.finishSendingMessage(CDROutputObject.java:200)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.sendResponse(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1554)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1497)
    ... 7 more
|#]
```

Comment: It looks like a TCP socket timeout to the remote host to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, it's a TCP timeout.

Maybe [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/ejcorba/entry/more_on_tcp_timeouts_in) helps?
(The broken link within the post is now [here.](https://blogs.oracle.com/ejcorba/entry/client_side_transport_timeouts_and))

Comment: Unfortunately none of the links works anymore and the info from there was not replicated here :-(
Any chance to dig up that old content again?

Comment: @Kosi2801 sorry, too long ago, I don't knwo about the details anymore...